# Apache uses excessive CPU

Tags: php, mysql, performance, apache

We run a medium-size site that gets a few hundred thousand pageviews a day. Up until last weekend we ran with a load usually below 0.2 on a virtual machine. The OS is Ubuntu.

When deploying the latest version of our application, we also did an apt-get dist-upgrade before deploying. After we had deployed we noticed that the load on the CPU had spiked dramatically (sometimes reaching 10 and stopping to respond to page requests).

We tried dumping a full minute of Xdebug profiling data from PHP, but looking through it revealed only a few somewhat slow parts, but nothing to explain the huge jump.

We are now pretty sure that nothing in the new version of our website is triggering the problem, but we have no way to be sure. We have rolled back a lot of the changes, but the problem still persists.

When look at processes, we see that single Apache processes use quite a bit of CPU over a longer period of time than strictly necessary. However, when using strace on the affected process, we never see anything but

```
accept(3,
```

and it hangs for a while before receiving a new connection, so we can't actually see what is causing the problem.

The stack is PHP 5, Apache 2 (prefork), MySQL 5.1. Most things run through Memcached. We've tried APC and eAccelerator.

So, what should be our next step? Are there any profiling methods we overlooked/don't know about?

Comment: From which versions to which versions did you upgrade the system? I mean a) PHP, b) Apache and c) memcached.

Comment: I do not have a log of that, unfortunately. As far as I know there is no apt-get/aptitude log.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer ended up being not-Apache related. As mentioned, we were on a virtual machine. Our user sessions are pretty big (think 500kB per active user), so we had a lot of disk IO. The disk was nearly full, meaning that Ubuntu spent a lot of time moving things around (or so we think). There was no easy way to extend the disk (because it was not set up properly for VMWare). This completely killed performance, and Apache and MySQL would occasionally use 100% CPU (for a very short time), and the system would be so slow to update the CPU usage meters that it seemed to be stuck there.

We ended up setting up a new VM (which also gave us the opportunity to thoroughly document everything on the server). On the new VM we allocated plenty of disk space, and moved sessions into memory (using memcached). Our load dropped to 0.2 on off-peak use and around 1 near peak use (on a 2-CPU VM). Moving the sessions into memcached took a lot of disk IO away (we were constantly using about 2MB/s of disk IO, which is very bad).

Conclusion; sometimes you just have to start over... :)

Answer (score 5):

Seeing an accept() call from your Apache process isn't at all unusual - that's the webserver waiting for a new request.

First of all, you want to establish what the parameters of the load are.  Something like

```
vmstat 1
```

will show you what your system is up to.  Look in the 'swap' and 'io' columns.  If you see anything other than '0' in the 'si' and 'so' columns, your system is swapping because of a low memory condition.  Consider reducing the number of running Apache children, or throwing more RAM in your server.

If RAM isn't an issue, look at the 'cpu' columns.  You're interested in the 'us' and 'sy' columns.  These show you the percentage of CPU time spent in either user processes or system.  A high 'us' number points the finger at Apache or your scripts - or potentially something else on the server.

Running

```
top
```

will show you which processes are the most active.

Have you ruled out your database?  The most common cause of unexpectedly high load I've seen on production LAMP stacks come down to database queries.  You may have deployed new code with an expensive query in it; or got to the point where there are enough rows in your dataset to cause previously cheap queries to become expensive.

During periods of high load, do

```
echo "show full processlist" | mysql | grep -v Sleep
```

to see if there are either long-running queries, or huge numbers of the same query operating at once.  Other mysql tools will help you optimise these.

You may find it useful to configure and use mod_status for Apache, which will allow you to see what request each Apache child is serving and for how long it has been doing so.

Finally, get some long-term statistical monitoring set up.  Something like zabbix is straightforward to configure, and will let you monitor resource usage over time, such that if things get slow, you have historical baselines to compare against, and a better ieda of when problems started.

Comment: The problem is Apache using the CPU. There is more than enough RAM (we ran on 512MB before the upgrade, now we have 2GB). No swapping is happening. MySQL slow query log reports nothing unusual. We are now seeing load spiking at 40, during heavy use.

Comment: mod_status is your best bet from here.  Also, to strace all of your Apache processes, rather than just the parent, try:

  ps aux | grep h[t]tpd | awk '{ print " -p"$2 }' | xargs strace

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you where using worker MPM before and now you are not?

I know PHP5 does not work with the Worker MPM. On my Ubuntu server, PHP5 can only be installed with the Prefork MPM. It seems that PHP5 module is not compatible with multithreading version of Apache.

I found a link here that will show you how to get better performance with [mod_fcgid](http://ivan.gudangbaca.com/installing_apache2_and_php5_using_mod_fcgid)

To see what worker MPM is see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/worker.html).

Comment: Out of ideas then I am afraid I thought you might of been using php4 in your old version of the application and now since the updrade to php5 apapche is running in prefork mode. Was your old version of the application using php4?

Comment: Maybe about a month old. We do upgrades before every deployment. We might stop doing that after this problem, though... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use dTrace to solve this mystery... if it was running on Solaris or Mac... but since Linux doesn't have it you might want to try their [Systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/), however I can't say anything about its usability since I haven't used it.

With dTrace you could easily sniff out the culprits within a day, and would hope with Systemtap it would be similiar

Comment: Systemtap seems a bit to complicated for now.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I can't assure you will do any good, but it's more than worth the effort. Is to read the detailed changelog for the new version, and review what might have changed that could remotely affect you.

Going through the changelogs has saved me  more than once. Especially when some config options have changed and when something got deprecated. Worst case is it'll give you some clues as to where to look next

Comment: For this case, it has not really helped. We did do this initially, and found some performance problems, but rolling back those changes did not solve the problem, unfortunately.